# Certification issue while installing rvm on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-16.04

When I am trying to install RVM, on Ubuntu 16.04. I am getting a certificate verification issue.
Please find the below screenshot for reference. Is that happened because of firewall or is it is related to RVM?

Please escape me from this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to isntall the public key that rvm requires, you need to install gnupg

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg gnupg2
```

Then you will able to install the public key

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

Now you can install rvm

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Comment: still I am getting the same issue :-(

Comment: and also while am running curl command and getting warning this warning **Warning: /home/iradmin/.curlrc:1: warning: secure** is unknown. can you please tell me how to fix this warning.

Comment: try:
    echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc
that should solve the warming,got the answer from a github issue:
    https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2989

Comment: After that command I started to get two warning **Warning: /home/iradmin/.curlrc:1: warning: 'secure' is unknown
Warning: /home/iradmin/.curlrc:2: warning: 'ip4' is unknown**